# refractoring jquery appending shortening code

Tags: jquery, refactoring, append

I have this script

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/file1.css" type="text/css" />');
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" type="text/css" />');
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image_contents.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Is this the best way to write this script? Is there a shorter easier or faster syntax? Sorry if i'm in the wrong place to ask this. I'm trying to refractor this multiple appending. Please shine some light,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function if you want:

```
function addCSS() {
   var paths = ["css/file1.css", "css/jquery.jscrollpane.css", "css/image_contents.css"];

   $.each(paths, function(i, path) {
     $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+path+'" type="text/css" />');
   });
}
```

Comment: i need to append them at the same time

Comment: @andrewliu: IT will be same if you call the function three times for your three files as you are doing now.

Comment: does this mean i'd have to put path in an array? how would I call the function three times? I'm still learning! would I have to do `path = array("css/file1.css", "css/jquery.jscrollpane.css", "css/image_contents.css");`

Comment: @andrewliu: See updated answer plz. In JS, arrays are creating using array literal `[]` or `new Array`, that's updated also.

Comment: Blaster's approach is sensible. Another option is perform one append call: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/file1.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image_contents.css" type="text/css" />');

Comment: @micahwittman: Yes I had that in mind also put thought OP would fine it to be same :)